# Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic 1.2.2 is not compatible with net7.0

Tags: .net-core, nuget, csproj

I've been working to migrate an inherited project away from older versions of .NETCore to version 7, but When I tried to restore from the `.csproj` file today I got this error message:

```
/src/app/ProjectNameHere.WebApi.csproj : error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic 1.2.2 is not compatible with net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0). Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic 1.2.2 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
```

Is there a drop-in replacement or something that I can use to move forwards with this migration? I haven't used .NET in the past so I'm not very familiar with nuget and the framework ecosystem as a whole.

Comment: ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core are sufficiently different such that libraries that support one won't work in the other (.NET 7 only supports ASP.NET Core). I know the names are confusing, especially for people new to the ecosystem, but it's also confusing for people who use it regularly. Anyway, using modern MVC controllers and other built-in ASP.NET Core routing APIs, it should be easy enough to write webhook receivers without needing any libraries.  What feature or API are you looking for?

Comment: @zivkan honestly I don't even think the library was used at all, I removed the dependency and the issue went away! Now I've got other issues, but this one is resolved... Could you maybe put an implementation of your suggestion in an answer to document it for others who may have the same issue?